# Android system update over lte

Tags: ota-update

I need some help regarding updating my Nexus 6p to Android nougat over lte connection. My lte connection is excellent with unlimited data plan, but Google seems to be tying my hands by forcing me to go for a WiFi network, which obviously I don't have an access to at present. Is there any way to force the update over my lte connection. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could download the OTA zip file from Google, then flash it using ADB commands which are in the Android SDK, so you'd need a computer as well:  [Official Google OTA link](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/ota)

*Taken from the above link:*

To apply an OTA update image:

1. Download the appropriate update image for your device.
2. Verify the checksum of the image: the OTA mechanism has a built-in validation feature, however verifying would save you some time in case the file was incomplete. The last portion of the filename is the first 8 digits of its SHA-256 checksum; the full SHA-256 checksum is also shown next to the download link.
3. With the device powered on and USB debugging enabled, execute:

   > adb reboot recovery

The device is now in recovery mode and an Android logo with red exclamation mark should appear on screen.

4. Hold Power button and press Volume Up once, and a menu will be shown. Select the option of

   > Apply update from ADB
5. Run the following command:

   > adb sideload (ota file.zip)

where (ota file.zip) is replaced with the file you have downloaded and verified.
Once the update finishes, you should reboot the phone by choosing:

> Reboot the system now